How to compare text between two columns for partial or exact matches
I need to check if any text from column A appears in any cell on column B (partial or exact), and, if possible, mark the cells in some way. For example in the screen shot- items in column A have a match (or partial match) on column B.
enter image description here
I already tried:
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0))), "Yes", "")

but this only worked for same-row text.

I've also tried this one:
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B,0))), "Yes", "")

Put it inside the C1 cell, and dragged it across the entirety of column C- It kinda works, but not in a convenient way.
